# How to make a self sizing basic UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I know how to make a custom self sizing cell. But for some reason I'm facing challenges when trying to make a default one multi-line.

What I currently want is a cell which only has one label. So the default one with a built-in style "Basic" seems to be the best solution for something as simple as that. However it only shows 2 lines of text.

My current set-up: a static `UITableView` and a `UITableViewController` containing outlets to some of the cells that need to be configured.

Things I tried:

- set number of lines to 0
- set table view's row height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
- override `heightForRowAtIndexPath` so that it always returns `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
- call `sizeToFit`, `setNeedsLayout`, `layoutIfNeeded` on the cell and/or content view and/or text label
- set custom cell height to 0 in storyboard
- increase vertical and horizontal content hugging priorities for the label

EDIT:

I guess I wasn't really clear about what exactly is the problem. I'm not using a custom cell. I'm trying to get away with the basic one.

[image: cell]

This means you can't add any constraints to its label. Sure, you can programmatically but since everything is managed internally for Apple's built-in styles it may result in a conflict.

Additional details:

At this point (as I mentioned above) I have a UITableViewController with outlets to specific cells: `@IBOutlet weak var descriptionCell: UITableViewCell!`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
  return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Is it really possible? Since I already spent too much time trying to avoid making a custom cell I'll finally go make it. Anyway any solution is welcome.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the right place for tutorials. I suggest you edit your question to show your tableview controller code, an image of your cell with constraints and list exactly what the problem is and what is not working. As it stands your question is too broad.

Comment: Follow the steps:- http://www.programmingcrew.in/2015/09/uitable-view-cell-dynamic-height-ios7.html

Comment: @RoboticCat okay, I edited the original post but there is still not much code involved. I thought I could get away with a basic cell but it turns out I can't.

Answer (score 0):

It's no need to do following two.

- call sizeToFit, setNeedsLayout, layoutIfNeeded on the cell and/or content view and/or text label
- set custom cell height to 0 in storyboard

And you should check you label's constraints. For example, it should has fixed width at run time and has constraints with cell's top and bottom. So the cell will grow itself.

Comment: That surely works unless you're using a cell with a built-in style ("Basic" in my case). I edited my original post with extra details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

1. Set number of lines to 0
2. Set table view's row height to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
3. Override `heightForRowAtIndexPath` so that it always returns `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`
4. `NsLayConstraints` for label:

   ```
   top = cell.top
   bottom = cell.bottom
   leading = cell.leading.padding 
   trailing = cell.leading.padding   (Padding is optional)
   ```

Comment: But there is really no good way of adding constraints to a label when using a built-in cell style ("Basic" in my case). I edited my original post with extra details.

Comment: without UITableViewAutomaticDimension and estimated height property you can not make it happen. according to my knowledge there isn't any way to do it.
you can not relay on constraints only.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me. All you need to do in your code is

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0 // or whatever height is closest to what your cells will be
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Everything you listed after "set table view's row height to UITableViewAutomaticDimension" is not necessary. Just set number of lines in your cell's label to 0 like you did and include the code above.